# Javascript & jQuery: appending an item and getting access to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have problem with Web App based on JS and jQuery. Generally, on the website I have button which triggers JavaScript function *onclicking*. In this function there are two other functions, I'll call them Foo and Bar. Foo creates dynamic html table with data and Bar wants to get some data from this table. It looks something like this:

```
function Click(){
    Foo();
    Bar();
}
function Foo(){
    $("#someDiv").append("html table");
}
function Bar(){
    var x = $("#selector_from_added_table").val();
}
```

I used *val* intentionally - in the table there are several *input* fields. My problem is simple: Variable *x* after calling sequence of *Foo()* and *Bar()* is undefined. But when I call *Bar()* inside *Foo()*, *x* gets proper value. But this solution is unacceptable, because I have to call *Bar()* several times.

Comment: Is `Foo` making an Ajax request to get the new HTML? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eBn9v/3/

adding a callback function in `Foo()` so that when you access element in Bar(), you are sure that the element does exits in DOM

## HTML:

```
    <div id="someDiv"></div>
    <div id="someOtherDiv">
      click me 
    </div>
```

## Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Click();
});

    function Click() {
    Foo(function () {
        Bar();
    });
}

function Foo(callback) {
    $("#someDiv").append("<table><tr><input type='text' value='Hello World' class='hi' /></tr></table>");
    callback();
}


function Bar() {
    var x = $('.hi').val();
    alert(x);
    }

$('#someOtherDiv').on("click", function() {
    Bar();
});
```

so now, when you create dynamic table inside one `someDiv`, you can call `BAR()` method from `#someOtherDiv` and show the value from `textbox` which exits in `someDiv`

Comment: Is this an answer? I just see a block of code. What are you trying to convey here? Please explain your answer.

Comment: well, he wants to call BAR() method and get the value from dynamically added textbox .. so he can now call BAR() from anywhere and get the value... first of all i did what i could understand from his question...

Comment: And how is this different than what the OP already has?

Comment: OP: i did not get it..

Comment: OP = original poster. How is this different from the code in the question?

Comment: OP has stated in his question that var x is undefined when he calls Foo() and Bar() in sequence.. he can call it in a sequence as well as he can access Bar() from anyother method as he stated that he wants to call Bar() several times..

Comment: Not sure if I get it. You are still calling `Foo` and `Bar` in a sequence and did note make any modifications to both of these functions. So why would `x` *not* be `undefined` in your code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43276/discussion-between-patel-milanb-and-felix-kling)

Comment: I think, dynamically created table s not yet ready when JS calls Bar() hence var x is undeinfed..

Comment: Well, now you changed your answer. This could indeed help.

Comment: yes, I think the problem was Bar() getting called before Foo() finishes creating dynamic table element..

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I've solved the problem using patel.milanb's code snippet and link given by Felix.